# Nginx as reverse proxy: "one armed" or multi-nic , in a dedicated VM environment?

Tags: nginx

Nginx 1.7.x and up on CentOS, on VMWare

Historically, I have always set up hardware load balancers like a firewall (public facing interface on one physical port, private facing interface on 2nd physical port), and software load balancers "one armed" (since it is all behind the firewall)

The questions:

1) In a production env, where everything (app servers, nginx) are all on vmware, should we do all the networking to do this, or leave it "one armed" ?

2) In a virtualized environment, do I care about networking as a possible bottleneck? (One armed means all the inbound and outbound traffic is across a single virtual and physical interface.)

I should further add that in the examples I see about, like https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/07/08/nginx-load-balancing-reverse-proxy-updated/, it seems one armed is everywhere. (This example looks one armed to me because the server is not listening on a specific IP, so it would appear it is running on a system that only has a single IP.)

(One armed means: One interface, perhaps with multiple IP addys, that handles all incoming and outgoing traffic.)

Comment: You can do it either way. The calculus doesn't change very much when the networks are virtual rather than physical. Nobody outside your datacenter will be able to tell the difference unless they break in, which presumably is what you're worried about.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This isn't about security or what people will think. It is about throughput and architectural correctness... OP enhanced. Thx for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) In a production env, where everything (app servers, nginx) are all
>   on vmware, should we do all the networking to do this, or leave it
>   "one armed" ?

This depends on the throughput requirements, and is basically the same as physical hardware - If you find the throughput of the NIC is a bottleneck then put in another virtual NIC mapped to a different physical NIC. If there's no bottleneck with throughput then latency should be essentially the same.

> 2) In a virtualized environment, do I care about networking as a
>   possible bottleneck? (One armed means all the inbound and outbound
>   traffic is across a single virtual and physical interface.)

You will likely only care if you hit one of the physical limits of the NIC on the VM host. In normal use cases you won't care unless the application is exceptionally sensitive to latency - think High Frequency Trading systems. Virtualization adds an amount of latency and there may be issues if you have contention for throughput between virtual hosts using the physical NIC - the physical NIC will still be the primary limiting factor. If it is then you can look at adding additional physical NICs and mapping virtual NICs to those, or scaling sideways to VMs running on a different host. Essentially the same decisions you would have to make if running physical servers, with more flexibility.